# launch long-running task then immediately send HTTP response

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, ktor

Using ktor HTTP server, I would like to launch a long-running task and immediately return a message to the calling client. The task is self-sufficient, it's capable of updating its status in a db, and a separate HTTP call returns its status (i.e. for a progress bar).

What I cannot seem to do is just launch the task in the background and respond. All my attempts at responding wait for the long-running task to complete. I have experimented with many configurations of `runBlocking` and `coroutineScope` but none are working for me.

```kotlin
// ktor route
get("/launchlongtask") {
    val text: String = (myFunction(call.request.queryParameters["loops"]!!.toInt()))
    println("myFunction returned")
    call.respondText(text)
}

// in reality, this function is complex... the caller (route) is not able to 
// determine the response string, it must be done here
suspend fun myFunction(loops : Int) : String {
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            // long-running task, I want to launch it and move on
            (1..loops).forEach {
                println("this is loop $it")
                delay(2000L)
                // updates status in db here
            }
        }
        println("returning")
        // this string must be calculated in this function (or a sub-function)
        return@runBlocking "we just launched $loops loops" 
    }
    return "never get here" // actually we do get here in a coroutineScope
}
```

output:

```
returning
this is loop 1
this is loop 2
this is loop 3
this is loop 4
myFunction returned
```

expected:

```
returning
myFunction returned
(response sent)
this is loop 1
this is loop 2
this is loop 3
this is loop 4
```

Answer (score 2):

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906172/1766526) by Lucas Milotich, I utilized `CoroutineScope(Job())` and it seems to work:

```
suspend fun myFunction(loops : Int) : String {
    CoroutineScope(Job()).launch { 
        // long-running task, I want to launch it and move on
        (1..loops).forEach {
            println("this is loop $it")
            delay(2000L)
            // updates status in db here
        }
    }
    println("returning")
    return "we just launched $loops loops" 
}
```

not sure if this is resource-efficient, or the preferred way to go, but I don't see a whole lot of other documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain the issue with the code in your question, the problem is using `runBlocking`. This is meant as the bridge between the synchronous world and the async world of coroutines and

> "the name of runBlocking means that the thread that runs it ... gets blocked for the duration of the call, until all the coroutines inside runBlocking { ... } complete their execution."

(from the [Coroutine docs)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency).

So in your first example, `myFunction` won't complete until your coroutine containing loop completes.

The correct approach is what you do in your answer, using CoroutineScope to launch your long-running task. One thing to point out is that you are just passing in a `Job()` as the `CoroutineContext` parameter to the `CoroutineScope` constructor. The `CoroutineContext` contains multiple things; `Job`, `CoroutineDispatcher`, `CoroutineExceptionHandler`... In this case, because you don't specifiy a `CoroutineDispatcher` it will use `CoroutineDispatcher.Default`. This is intended for CPU-intensive tasks and will be limited to ["the number of CPU cores (with a minimum of 2)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039991/difference-between-usage-of-dispatcher-io-and-default). This may or may not be want you want. An alternative is CoroutineDispatcher.IO - which has a default of 64 threads.

Comment: First -- thanks very much! Yes I understand the problem with `runBlocking`, I had also tried it in the caller and also `coroutineScope` instead, and various other combos. My frustration is more the lack of, or very limited documentation -- [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads) covers contexts and dispatchers but doesn't address this use case (returning a value from a function, during which, a new coroutine is launched), or differentiate `coroutineScope {}`, `coroutineScope()`, and `CoroutineScope {}`. In any case, thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I've been frustrated by a lot of the documentation around coroutines