Ktor: launch long-running task then immediately send HTTP response
How do I properly launch a long-running task in Ktor sever without waiting for its completion, i.e.
launch and immediately send the HTTP response back.
In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73930834/12570695
Something like this is suggested:

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
        // long-running task
}

However, in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843232
This approach is highly discouraged because it creates an unmanaged coroutine scope.
How to do it properly?

You can use the launch(Dispatchers.IO) call to launch a background task, creating a child coroutine dependent on the parent in the route's handler.

@AlekseiTirman I think launch can only be called as a method a coroutineScope object. You cannot call it stand-alone.

I think I found an answer. Based on this documentation: https://api.ktor.io/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/io.ktor.server.application/-application/index.html
"Represents configured and running web application, capable of handling requests. It is also the application coroutine scope that is cancelled immediately at application stop so useful for launching background coroutines."
Based on this, I assume the correct approach would be:
routing {
    get("/") {
        call.application.launch(Dispatcher.IO) {
            //Long running task
        }
    }
}


That looks good. You need an already existing coroutine scope that outlives your current request. application seems well suited for that.
